# Do I need a sound for this dead body?

Tags: theater, theatre-sound-design

The scene is simple.  Stereotypical murder mystery mansion situation.  Someone opens a closet.  A dead body falls out of the closet, make a dull thud.  The director is convinced that we need to add a sound effect for this, most of the technical people are firmly set on no, but some say we should try it and the director insists.  Thoughts? (and  how do i make it not sound terrible if we do)

Comment: I would say you definitely need the thud. Is the problem that the director thinks the existing thud is too boring, or is there currently no sound at all?

Comment: he thinks the existing thud is too boring.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing the context or hearing your director's request, my thought is that he's looking for an emotional sound that will supplement the practical sound of the body hitting the floor, ie. a "stinger" or something that will provoke a reaction from the audience.

Is that what the director is getting at? Or is the sound supposed to be some other type of practical sound, ie. a heavy creak of the floor under the weight of the body, a big slam that resonates through the room, a slap of skin against wood floor, etc.

Comment: @Jasper, how did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you search your libraries for "body fall" you will find a convincing sound effect. I do these all the time and they do make the scene more realistic, especially if the actor tried to save herself while falling.

Hens Zimmerman